# Meaning of “touch the rock”

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, slang

In *Coach Carter,* a basketball team loses a game and the members argue with each other in the locker room:

> Timo, you was in [the game] the whole time, you never even **touched the rock.**
> <sub>Source: [script-o-rama.com, *Coach Carter* Script – Dialogue Transcript](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/c/coach-carter-script-transcript.html)</sub>

What does “touched the rock” mean?

Comment: I think you need more context. Can you transcribe a bit more of the scene before that statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In basketball, "the rock" is a [slang term](http://en.mimi.hu/m/basketball/rock.html) for the ball.

"You never touched the rock" in this case is an observation that the player in question did not handle the ball at any point, meaning they did not steal, rebound, pass, or shoot. Someone taking up one of five positions on the court without influencing the game through these actions will likely be considered as having a negative impact on the performance of the team.

Comment: Is [that](http://www.anacondateamstore.com/amazon/MG-4000-PC-MC14.jpg) what you meant?

Comment: @Dmitry That product makes use of the slang term for its name, but the term can refer to any basketball.

Comment: You're right about what it means, but I'd say two things about your interpretation: It's not necessarily a "complaint" (it could be a simple observation), and it doesn't necessarily imply a negative impact on the team's performance, especially if Timo is a role player who doesn't get a lot of minutes. Timo could have been playing good man-to-man defense, so the other team never passed the ball in his direction. He may have been boxing out, but the rebounds bounced to the other side of the hoop. (I haven't seen the movie, though; with more context, your observations might be correct.)

Comment: @J.R. I’ve edited to make the answer more generally applicable, but I think if you look at the next couple of lines in the script you’ll see it’s definitely a complaint.